# Bad website responsive

Tags: html, css, browser, responsive-design

I am making new website but I got one small problem. When I resize browser or zoom in the buttons moves to stupid places.

[Normal sized browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cg3Ml.png)

[Smaller browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUQ28.png)

Index.html:

```
<head>

    <title>SquareWorld</title>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>

    <link href="styles/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

</head>

<body>

    <header>

        <nav>

            <h1>SquareWorld</h1>

            <ul>

                <li><center><a href="#">Home</a></center></li>
                <li><center><a href="#">Video</a></center></li>
                <li><center><a href="#">Contact</a></center></li>
                <li><center><a href="#">Register</a></center></li>
                <li><center><a href="#">Download</a></center></li>

            </ul>

        </nav>

    </header>



</body>
```

Styles/index.css:

```
body {

margin: 0;
font-family: arial;

}

header {

background: #585858;
color: white;
padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;

}

header h1 {

margin: 0;
display: inline;

}

nav ul {

margin: 0;
display: inline;

}

nav ul li {

list-style-type: none;
display: inline-block;
color: white;
background: black;
min-width: 100px;
border-radius: 15px;
position: relative;
padding: 5px 15px;

}

nav ul li a {

color: white;

}
```

Is there anyway to make it look better or can I get link to somekind responsive course?
Thanks for helping!

Comment: Take a course in responsive design, you will find it very helpful

Comment: There are many responsive frameworks you can use, like bootstrap for example, that enable you to define how you want your content to be positioned on different sized screens.  You could also just use media queries in your own CSS and put your buttons exactly where you want them for different sized screens - but honestly it's easier to just use bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend adding break points. For example, when you resize your window to 700 pixels you want the code to display a certain way.

@media (max-width:700px){
   nav ul li {display: block: /*This will make the nav items display in a single line; which will only show up when the browser is resized at 700px and below.*/ }

}

@media (max-width:400px){
  }

You can also look up Bootstrap, Foundation, or Skeleton. These three are great frameworks, and make responsive design much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You are using css rules that are making the link-boxes being displayed as text. The browser is automatically adding some "line breaks" when an element reaches the visual end of it's parent element. You could avoid this problem by using **media-queries**. With these you can define for example **different css styles for different screen sizes**.

Here's an example css that fits to your website:

```
@media (max-width: 900px) {
    nav ul li {
        min-width: 50px;
        max-width: 50px;
        font-size: 0.75em;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 700px) {
    nav ul li {
        min-width: 25px;
        max-width: 25px;
        font-size: 0.5em;
    }
    header h1 {
        font-size: 0.75em;
    }
}
```

> Note: This code is **additional** to your css code!

Explanation: There are two media-queries. The css rules in a media query only affect anything when its conditions (for example the window width has to be less than 900px) are fulfilled.
The first query defines the link-boxes to get a width of 50 pixels and the font size is reduced by 25% (75% of the surrounding font size).
When the window size is less than 700 pixels the boxes' width is set to 25px, the font size gets changed and the headline's size will be decreased.

You can find more examples and a list of conditions here:
[w3schools: CSS3 @media Rule](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Answer (score 0):

[Responsive Grid Syste](http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/)m is a great "framework" for a simplistic responsive website. It is based on media queries to set the pixel width break points of the browser window. Start there. Bootstrap is a more robust framework that when used correctly is inherently responsive. Start there.